# Windows 11 Notepad App Takes Up HUGE Memory

Tags: memory, windows-11, notepad

I recently got Windows 11 after retiring Windows 7 and I am not impressed.

Notepad (came with the system) when just opened, takes up 44 MB Memory. No wonder I see many forums stating Notepad is slow. Windows Explorer takes up 113 MB Memory!

Notepad takes up a lot more memory than 5 Excel files with content (3-5 sheets each with content and formula) using 15 MB and two Word Docs with formatting using 3.6 MB total (version 2010 that works okay on Win 11. I use a lot of formula like index and match that doesn't increase Excel memory much, if at all.).

Yet, Notepad, that came with this Win 11 computer, has zero content taking up 44 MB!

Can anyone explain why Notepad (without formatting) takes up so much memory?

Might there be a hack/virus/malware installed that is doing that? I have McAfee running for malware.

Is there some setting to minimize that wasted use of memory?

Or, should I install the Notepad from my Win 7 (is that even possible)?

Comment: "Might there be a hack/virus/malware installed that is doing that?" - This absolutely is not happening

Comment: When I start Notepad it uses 10MB (goes down to 8 after a minute) according to the first tab in taskmanager. As far as I know virus scanner like MacAfee are not better compared to Windows defender. So you you can save that money and deinstall it.

Comment: Like @Robert, 9.8mb .. then down to 8.  Opens in less than one second.  Aside from that.. `should I install the Notepad from my Win 7` .. ? Notepad is a featureless editor.  I don't know why one would even use it (unless in a pinch).  Try any one of the plethora of free editors that are superior in every way.  I suggest [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) if you want free and fast but there are plenty others.

Comment: 40MB is a tiny amount of memory, even if it's more than others report theirs is using. 100mb is also tiny in modern computers.